# WinAPI. Нижняя строка меню, с изображениями

Tags: winapi

Знаю как создается строка меню типа File, Edit и т.д Но у всех приложений также дополнительно под ней находится строка меню с теми же функциями, но как кнопки с символами. Они тоже создаются функциями типа:

```
CreateMenu();
AppendMenuW(file, MF_STRING, IDM_FILE_OPEN, L"&Open Image");
```

Или они создаются уже просто как обычные кнопки типа "BUTTON" ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это не кнопки и не меню. Это стандартный контрол, который называется [toolbar](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/toolbar-control-reference). Он может создаваться динамически, но обычно он создаётся в ресурсах. Для этого в .rc есть отдельный тип ресурса `TOOLBAR`.

Посмотрите [How to Create Toolbars](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/create-toolbars), ещё можете в поисковике набрать "создание тулбара winapi", примеров и всяких руководств полно.